# How can an non-amphibious plant or zombie end up in a water lane?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-heroes

I was playing PvZ Heroes and noticed that my opponent did something that managed to put a non-amphibious zombie (in this case a cell phone zombie) into the water lane of my match.  How can this happen, since this type of zombie cannot normally be played in a water lane?

[image: Lanes]

<sup>(This is a canonical Q&A pair to present my findings to future visitors)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, any amphibious plant can be transformed into a non-amphibious plant and remain in a water lane using a trick card such as Petal-Morphosis (there is also an equivalent zombie card which I have not unlocked yet).  There is also a zombie equivalent which will transform any zombie into a 1/1 goat, which can cause a goat to end up in a water lane as well.

[image: Petal-Morphosis]

Answer (score 0):

What your opponent played was Transmogrify, a 1-cost Smarty superpower owned by Rose and Citron. It transformes a zombie into a random zombie costing 2 brains or less. Your opponent transmogrified an amphibious zombie (likely Dolphin Rider) in the water into a cell phone zombie.